# Having trouble with FileReader, vscode terminal printing my text document quotation marks with â?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, filereader

The files "output.txt" and "outputTwo.txt" works fine with quotation mark but the file "readme.txt" has a different icon on vscode and prints the quotation marks as â??

[image: Sample image]

Code:

```java
public static void readFile() {
        
        try{
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("readme.txt");
            int data = fr.read();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("readme.txt"));
            String line;

            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            
            br.close();
           
        } catch (IOException e){

        }
       
    }
```

Terminal:

```
The tongue has no bones, but bones it crashes. â?? Greek Proverb
â??Wine and children speak the truth.â??
â?? Greek Proverb
â??One thing I know, that I know nothing. This is the source of my wisdom.â??
â?? Socrates
â??Wise men speak because they have something to say; Fools because they have to say something.â??
â?? Plato
â??It is more important to know what sort of person has a disease than to know what sort of disease a person has.â??
â?? Hippocrates
```

Outcome: Why is it replacing the quotation marks with â??

Comment: These are not regular quotation marks but special UTF8 characters. Either your default encoding is not utf8 which makes your application read the file incorrectly or your terminal does not support printing these characters.

Comment: @f1sh's comment is the right answer

Comment: How do I fix this

Comment: @MarcIsip `new FileReader("readme.txt", StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`. As an aside, it is never a good idea to have an empty catch block in Java, as it will prevent you from seeing important diagnostic information when an exception is thrown. At the very least, call `e.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: Also if you use Java >= 17, it should automatically read that file as UTF-8 (its probable encoding). *Your* probable platform encoding is a localized Windows one